# Alibaba cloud Apache slow transfer graphics

Tags: networking, graphics, apache2, data-transfer, alibaba-cloud-ecs

I’m trying out Alicloud ECS, and have set up a full commerce site.

The network bandwidth of this instance is 1Mb/sec. Now it takes up to 10 seconds to finish loading a bunch of <100KB graphics files!

I’m seeking ways to find out the root causes of this. Please share.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into two directions.

1. Check if the ECS instance is working as expected. Check its CPU load performance in the Cloud Monitor. If the ECS instance is a burstable ECS type, it will have a baseline CPU performance, your ECS should operate under this baseline.
2. Check the network link state between your user end to the ECS instance public IP. Generally a higher latency or packet loss is a cause of such issues. You can use the MTR tool to see if there is some packet loss over the link.

For link testing with MTR, you can refer to: [Link testing for ping packet loss or ping failure](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/faq-detail/40573.htm)